# Unable to connect server using LDAP SSL?

Tags: c++, objective-c, ios8, openldap, ldapconnection

Below is the code i am using for connecting LDAPS server

```
/* Open LDAP Connection */
if( ldap_initialize( &ld, ldapServer ) )//Success Response
{
    perror( "ldap_initialize" );
    //return( OTHER );
}

NSString* filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"server"
                                                     ofType:@"pem"];
int version =  LDAP_VERSION3;
ldap_set_option(ld, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, &version);    
ldap_set_option(ld, LDAP_OPT_X_TLS_CACERTFILE, NULL);
ldap_set_option(ld, LDAP_OPT_X_TLS_CERTFILE,(__bridge const void *)(filePath));
ldap_set_option(ld, LDAP_OPT_X_TLS_KEYFILE, (__bridge const void *)(filePath));
rc = ldap_start_tls_s(ld, NULL, NULL);  //Failure Response (LDAP_INAPPROPRIATE_MATCHING)
if( rc != LDAP_SUCCESS ){
    printf("start tls failed.\n");
    exit(0);
}
```

here ldap_start_tls_s is giving Failure Response **(LDAP_INAPPROPRIATE_MATCHING)**

any one can help me where i done mistake.

If you find any useful links pleases do share with me.

Answer (score 1):

Casting from `NSString` to `const void *` cannot be right:

```
ldap_set_option(ld, LDAP_OPT_X_TLS_CERTFILE,(__bridge const void *)(filePath));
ldap_set_option(ld, LDAP_OPT_X_TLS_KEYFILE, (__bridge const void *)(filePath));
```

You probably want:

```
ldap_set_option(ld, LDAP_OPT_X_TLS_CERTFILE, [filePath UTF8String]);
ldap_set_option(ld, LDAP_OPT_X_TLS_KEYFILE,  [filePath UTF8String]);
```

Comment: any sample code is ther  pls share with me? I am unable to continue further. If any link is also apprisiatable ..